# Send an image and other string parameters to server using HttpURLConnection and Base64

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-bundle

I am trying to send an image and some string values from android to a php script using HttpURLConnection. I have successfully done so with strings, but can't seem to get it right with the image. I am using Base64 (android.util.Base64) to convert my image to a string to send it. Now, I have a separate HttpParse.java file I use to send all my info to the server, and I think that is where the change needs to be made to allow the image, but I'm not sure, (I am newer to java/android development). I've researched several similar questions, but they aren't fully clicking for me for what I'm doing wrong. Also, I have tested that I am successfully converting the image to a string. Here is my code:

**EDIT** I got a little farther... After testing, I am getting the issue because the three variables I try to get with getArguments() are coming back as null... But, I can't figure out how to get them to come through successfully... I added the code for how I start my fragment and how I try to get my bundle

My fragment start:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_units);

    Intent intent = getIntent();

    LexaUser = intent.getStringExtra("UserName");
    ReadOnly = intent.getStringExtra("ReadOnly");
    Password = intent.getStringExtra("Password");
    QA = intent.getStringExtra("QA");
    SearchValue = intent.getStringExtra("SearchInput");

    bottomNavigation = (BottomNavigationView)findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
    bottomNavigation.inflateMenu(R.menu.bottom_menu);
    fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

    bottomNavigation.getMenu().getItem(0).setChecked(true);

    UnitDetailsHeader = findViewById(R.id.UnitDetailsViewTitle);
    UnitDetailsHeader.setText(SearchValue);

    UnitSizeText = findViewById(R.id.UnitSize);
    UnitStatusText = findViewById(R.id.UnitStatus);

    if (SearchValue.contains("-")) {
        getUnitDetails(SearchValue, LexaUser);
    } else {
        getSiblings();
    }

    bottomNavigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            int id = item.getItemId();

            switch (id){
                case R.id.action_search:
                    fragment = new NewUnitStatusFragment();
                    break;
                case R.id.action_cart:
                    fragment = new PendingUnitStatusFragment();
                    break;
                case R.id.action_hot_deals:
                    fragment = new FinalUnitStatusFragment();
                    break;
                case R.id.action_siblings:
                    fragment = new SiblingUnitFragment();
                    break;
            }

            Bundle connBundle = new Bundle();
            connBundle.putString("SearchValue", SearchValue);
            connBundle.putString("LexaUser", LexaUser);
            connBundle.putString("Password", Password);
            connBundle.putString("QA", QA);

            fragment.setArguments(connBundle);

            final FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.main_container, fragment).commit();

            return true;
        }
    });


}
```

And where I try to get my arguments: (I originally had in onCreateView but then tried to move it to onCreate. But the behavior was the same)

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (getArguments() != null) {
        SearchValue = getArguments().getString("SearchValue");
        LexaUser = getArguments().getString("LexaUser");
        Password = getArguments().getString("Password");
    }
}
```

My fragment where I get the image and send my data:

```
package [my_package];

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.SpinnerAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import android.util.Base64;
import java.util.HashMap;

import static android.app.Activity.RESULT_OK;

public class NewUnitStatusFragment extends Fragment {

    Context newUnitStatusContext;
    Activity newUnitStatusActivity;

    Intent cameraIntent;

    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    String ReadOnly;
    String LexaUser;
    String Password;
    String SearchValue;

    String finalResultNewUnitStatus;
    String HttpURLNewUnitStatus = "https://[path/to/file]/insertNewUnitStatus.php";
    HashMap<String, String> hashMapNewUnitStatus = new HashMap<>();
    HttpParse httpParse = new HttpParse();

    Spinner statusSpinner;
    Spinner generalCauseSpinner;
    EditText newUSComment;
    Button addPhotoBtn;
    ImageView newUnitStatusImage;

    Button addNewUnitStatus;

    String newUnitStatus;
    String generalCause;
    String newUnitStatusComment;
    String newUnitStatusPhoto;

    String message;

    private static final int PICK_FROM_GALLERY = 1;


    public NewUnitStatusFragment() {
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_newunitstatus, container, false);

        newUnitStatusContext = getContext();
        newUnitStatusActivity = getActivity();

        statusSpinner = view.findViewById(R.id.Status);
        generalCauseSpinner = view.findViewById(R.id.GeneralCause);
        newUSComment = view.findViewById(R.id.NewComment);
        newUnitStatusImage = view.findViewById(R.id.AddPhoto);
        addPhotoBtn = view.findViewById(R.id.AddPhotosLabel);
        addNewUnitStatus = view.findViewById(R.id.addBtnNewUnitStatus);

        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> statusSpinnerAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(newUnitStatusContext,
            R.array.new_unit_status_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

        statusSpinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        statusSpinner.setAdapter(statusSpinnerAdapter);

        newUnitStatus = statusSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> generalCauseSpinnerAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(newUnitStatusContext,
            R.array.status_general_cause_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

        generalCauseSpinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        generalCauseSpinner.setAdapter(generalCauseSpinnerAdapter);

        generalCause = generalCauseSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

        addPhotoBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startGallery();
            }
        });

        // Set a click listener for the text view
        addNewUnitStatus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                newUnitStatus = statusSpinner.toString();
                generalCause = generalCauseSpinner.toString();
                newUnitStatusComment = newUSComment.toString();

                if (getArguments() != null) {
                    SearchValue = getArguments().getString("SearchValue");
                    LexaUser = getArguments().getString("LexaUser");
                    Password = getArguments().getString("Password");
                }

                addNewUnitStatus(SearchValue, newUnitStatus, generalCause, newUnitStatusComment, newUnitStatusPhoto, LexaUser, Password);

            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    private void startGallery() {
    cameraIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        cameraIntent.setType("image/*");
        cameraIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        if (cameraIntent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 1000);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(newUnitStatusContext, "Error: " + cameraIntent + " - cameraIntent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) = null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        //super method removed
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == 1000) {
                Uri returnUri = data.getData();
                try {
                    Bitmap bitmapImage = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), returnUri);
                    newUnitStatusImage.setImageBitmap(bitmapImage);

                    newUnitStatusImage.buildDrawingCache();
                    Bitmap bm = newUnitStatusImage.getDrawingCache();
                    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
                    byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();

                    newUnitStatusPhoto = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);

                } catch (IOException ioEx) {
                    ioEx.printStackTrace(); 
                    Toast.makeText(newUnitStatusContext, "ioEx Error: " + ioEx, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(newUnitStatusContext, "Error: " + requestCode, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(newUnitStatusContext, "Error: " + resultCode, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    public void addNewUnitStatus(String searchInput, String newUnitStatus, String generalCause, String newUnitStatusComment, String newUnitStatusPhoto, String lexaUser, String password) {

        class NewUnitStatusClass extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();

                progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(newUnitStatusContext, "Loading Data", null, true, true);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String httpResponseMsg) {

                super.onPostExecute(httpResponseMsg);

                if (httpResponseMsg != null) {

                    try {

                        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(httpResponseMsg);

                        message = object.getString("message");

                        Toast.makeText(newUnitStatusContext, httpResponseMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.e("JSONException", "Error: " + e.toString());
                        Toast.makeText(newUnitStatusContext, "Error: " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } // catch (JSONException e)

                    progressDialog.dismiss();

                } else {

                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(newUnitStatusContext, "HttpResponseMsg is null.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

                hashMapNewUnitStatus.put("searchinput", params[0]);
                hashMapNewUnitStatus.put("newUnitStatus", params[1]);
                hashMapNewUnitStatus.put("generalCause", params[2]);
                hashMapNewUnitStatus.put("newUnitStatusComment", params[3]);
                hashMapNewUnitStatus.put("newUnitStatusPhoto", params[4]);
                hashMapNewUnitStatus.put("lexauser", params[5]);
                hashMapNewUnitStatus.put("password", params[6]);

                finalResultNewUnitStatus = httpParse.postRequest(hashMapNewUnitStatus, HttpURLNewUnitStatus);

                return finalResultNewUnitStatus;
            }
        }
        NewUnitStatusClass newUnitStatusClass = new NewUnitStatusClass();
        newUnitStatusClass.execute(searchInput, newUnitStatus, generalCause, newUnitStatusComment, newUnitStatusPhoto, lexaUser, password);
    }
}
```

And my code to do that actuall HttpURLConnection: HttpParse.java

```
package [my_package];

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class HttpParse extends ListActivity {

    String FinalHttpData = "";
    String Result;
    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter;
    OutputStream outputStream;
    BufferedReader bufferedReader;
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    URL url;

    public String postRequest(HashMap<String, String> Data, String HttpUrlHolder) {

        try {
            url = new URL(HttpUrlHolder);

            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            httpURLConnection.setReadTimeout(14000);

            httpURLConnection.setConnectTimeout(14000);

            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");

            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);

            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);

            outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();

            bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(

                new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));

            bufferedWriter.write(FinalDataParse(Data));

            bufferedWriter.flush();

            bufferedWriter.close();

            outputStream.close();

            if (httpURLConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(
                            httpURLConnection.getInputStream()
                    )
                );
                FinalHttpData = bufferedReader.readLine();
            }
            else {
                FinalHttpData = "Something Went Wrong";
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return FinalHttpData;
    }

    public String FinalDataParse(HashMap<String,String> hashMap2) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

        for(Map.Entry<String,String> map_entry : hashMap2.entrySet()){

            stringBuilder.append("&");

            stringBuilder.append(URLEncoder.encode(map_entry.getKey(), "UTF-8"));

            stringBuilder.append("=");

            stringBuilder.append(URLEncoder.encode(map_entry.getValue(), "UTF-8"));

        }

       Result = stringBuilder.toString();

        return Result ;
    }
}
```

All help is appreciated! Thank you!

P.S. my app shows the following error:

```
W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference
```

This then leads to this:

```
E/JSONException: Error: org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of
```

Comment: Which line is throwing the error? In the logcat is the line also noticed, but you didn't add that.

Comment: at java.net.URLEncoder.encode(URLEncoder.java:205)

Comment: And why you didn't debug the moment, where it throws the error? Also I'm pretty sure, that you should use AsyncTask or any other asynchronous logic for any HTTP request, because it blocks the UI and could throws Exception.